# WildCard to Skip Synchronized DB

Tags: availability-groups

I am running a security RAG on reporting server that updates our security and put database to read_only mode. I am using wildcard to skip system and some other databases, but what can I use to skip any database that's a part of AG. in other words what can I use to skip synchronized DB?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `sys.databases where replica_id is NULL` . This will skip db that is part of AlwaysON Availability group. For sync db to be skipped, below answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> but what can I use to skip any database that's a part of AG. in other
>   words what can I use to skip synchronized DB?

There is a difference between  getting any database that belongs to an AG or to only get the synchronized databases. For example, async nodes will keep having the status: "synchronizing" (or another message, but not synchronized).

**To get all the databases participating in an AG:**

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id 
NOT IN (SELECT database_id  
        FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states);
```

**To get only the synchronizing databases:**

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id 
NOT IN (SELECT database_id  
        FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states 
        WHERE synchronization_state_desc = 'SYNCHRONIZED');
```

**To also exclude the system db's:**

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id 
NOT IN (SELECT database_id  
        FROM sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states 
        WHERE synchronization_state_desc = 'SYNCHRONIZED')
        AND database_id > 4;
```